# AWS copilot deployed service is not accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a simple backend srevice that I just deployed with copilot.
However, I don't know where to access it?

According to AWS console it's running and active. I can even see it in the logs that it has been started.

My manifest:

```
# The manifest for the "user-service" service.
# Read the full specification for the "Backend Service" type at:
#  https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/backend-service/

# Your service name will be used in naming your resources like log groups, ECS services, etc.
name: user-service
type: Backend Service

# Your service does not allow any traffic.

# Configuration for your containers and service.
image:
  # Docker build arguments. For additional overrides: https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/backend-service/#image-build
  build: ./Dockerfile
  port: 9000

cpu: 256       # Number of CPU units for the task.
memory: 512    # Amount of memory in MiB used by the task.
count: 1       # Number of tasks that should be running in your service.

# Optional fields for more advanced use-cases.
#
variables:                    # Pass environment variables as key value pairs.
  SERVER_PORT: 9000
  NODE_ENV: test
  
secrets:                      # Pass secrets from AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Parameter Store.
  ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
  REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET: REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET
  MONGODB_URL: MONGODB_URL

# You can override any of the values defined above by environment.
environments:
  test:
    variables:
      NODE_ENV: test
#    count: 2               # Number of tasks to run for the "test" environment.
```

My Dockerfile

```
# Check out https://hub.docker.com/_/node to select a new base image
FROM node:lts-buster-slim

# Set to a non-root built-in user `node`
USER node

# Create app directory (with user `node`)
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY --chown=node package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source code
COPY --chown=node . .

RUN npm run build

# Bind to all network interfaces so that it can be mapped to the host OS
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE 9000
CMD [ "node", "." ]
```

This works fine locally, with docker-compose. But where can I find the URL of the deployed service? I checked ECS console and the task has a public IP. However I can't connect to that.

What's missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Nm.. my bad. Backend services are not supposed to be reachable via internet. They expose endpoints but should talk to each other (or the frontend) via service discovery.

Comment: Same exact question. I deployed a simple Dockerized React app with nginx image via AWS Copilot and am not sure where to find the url. Should I have chosen something other than 'Backend Service' for this? Thanks.